# How do I run an iPhone GameSalad App on an iOS Device?

Tags: ios, gamesalad

I have made a simple game application with GameSalad . It runs fine in the iPhone simulator after loading the GameSalad Viewer but doesn't work in the device as it gives a code signing error. If I change the IPA according to the device then the GameSalad Viewer crashes and the app does not run.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: I get a debugger error when I run the GameSalad Viewer. I'm running:
- MacOS X 10.6.8;
- Xcode 3.2.5. I've checked the link, http://forums.gamesalad.com/discussion/37320/error-from-debugger, and it appears I need to upgrade my Xcode to a version 4 series.

Answer (score 2):

I installed Xcode 4.2 on MacOS X 10.6.8 and I can run the GameSalad viewer on my iPod Touch.  The GameSalad viewer needs to be built in Xcode 4.2 or later.